# How to find using Kusto query language if a column name contains 'teams' in a database and return all table and column names?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I want to find out all the column names that contain 'teams' in a particular database using Kusto queries.
The output should be the TableName and ColumnNames that satisfy this criteria.

Please help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use `.show database schema`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/show-schema-database

for example:

```
.show database MyDatabase schema
| where ColumnName contains 'teams'
| project TableName, ColumnName
```

or

```
.show database MyDatabase schema
| where ColumnName contains 'teams'
| summarize Columns = make_list(ColumnName) by TableName
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated!!

Comment: It is a saviour. Thanks for sharing.